# Is there a simple way of setting up rethinkdb mirrors?

Tags: rethinkdb

For example this will start two servers in a cluster

```
() rethinkdb -n A --directory DATA_A
() rethinkdb -n B --directory DATA_B --port-offset 1 --join localhost:29015
```

However they aren't mirrors/replicas as DATA_A and DATA_B aren't equivalent.

So, essentially I'm wondering if there's a way to start a cluster or server that would mirror databases and/or tables, whereby a new mirror could be added at any time and it would essentially catch up with another database or table and then continue syncing in real time.

Then, at any time any mirror could be dumped and the archives would be equivalent.

Any info would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done for each table by setting the `replica` key on `reconfigure ()` or `tableCreate ()`.

e.g.

```
() rethinkdb -n A --directory DATA_A --bind all
() rethinkdb -n B --directory DATA_B --port-offset 1 --join localhost:29015
() rethinkdb -n C --directory DATA_C --port-offset 2 --join localhost:29015
```

(JS) After Connecting and Creating up a Database

```
    var db = "";
    var table = "";
    r.db (db).tableCreate (table, {
        replicas: 3
    }).
    run (connection, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

Afterwards all documents inserted in `table` should be present in all three data directories.

```
() rethinkdb-dump -c localhost:28015 -f A.tar.gz
() rethinkdb-dump -c localhost:28016 -f B.tar.gz
() rethinkdb-dump -c localhost:28017 -f C.tar.gz
```